# Reporting Services - 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration

Tags: web, iis, reporting-services

I have an application that connects to Reporting Services in SQL Server 2012. After moving it to a new environment Reporting isn't working. Also, It doesn't work if I run IE as Administrator, when I'm trying to open http://localhost/Reports  I receive that error.
What should I check?

rsreportserver.config:

```
URLReservations>
    <Application>
        <Name>ReportServerWebService</Name>
        <VirtualDirectory>ReportServer</VirtualDirectory>
        <URLs>
            <URL>
                <UrlString>http://+:80</UrlString>
                <AccountSid>S-1-5-80-2885764129-887777008-271615777-1616004480-2722851051</AccountSid>
                <AccountName>NT Service\ReportServer</AccountName>
            </URL>
        </URLs>
    </Application>
    <Application>
        <Name>ReportManager</Name>
        <VirtualDirectory>Reports</VirtualDirectory>
        <URLs>
            <URL>
                <UrlString>http://+:80</UrlString>
                <AccountSid>S-1-5-80-2885764129-887777008-271615777-1616004480-2722851051</AccountSid>
                <AccountName>NT Service\ReportServer</AccountName>
            </URL>
        </URLs>
    </Application>
</URLReservations>
<Authentication>
    <AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsNegotiate/>
    </AuthenticationTypes>
```

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/iis/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7) to see details about 401.2 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: @samwu As I understand SSRS is a separate utility and it should be configured from Reporting Services Configuration Manager. Well, you provided a link that required configuration in IIS. But my website working fine, only with SSRS I'm experiencing problems.